# How to filter specific applications for (share) Email intent?

Tags: android

I am using Action Send and createChooser APIs in my app to share some text message through various Email apps.But I dont want all the apps that i have installed in my device.I want specifically facebook,Gmail and Twitter to be in the that chooser List.How to filter like this?Thanks

```
String TEXT = "I shared the file " + " via MyApp";
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TEXT);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share the program:"));
```

This is the code I am using.

Answer (score 3):

If you know, which apps you want, you can create your own chooser in a Dialog, and fire the specific intent according to the user's selection.

You can check available applications by invoking PackageManager's queryIntentActivities:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( sendIntent, 0);
```

And then you select the ones you need and pop up the dialog.

Comment: Thanks Andras.Is there any way to filter in the createChooser() API.b ecause i want the default share screen.

Comment: Also, is there a way to filter by app type (text, email, etc...)?